# sed replace double quoted text, single quoted working

Tags: bash, sed

I am using SED to replace some key words in the Wordpress config file (setup-config.php).

The code located below is what I am using the change the keyworkds

```
sed -i -e "s/( 'wordpress'/( '$varname'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
sed -i -e "s/( 'username'/( '$varname'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
sed -i -e "s/( 'password'/( '$autogenpass'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
sed -i -e "s/( 'wp_'/( '$autogenprefix'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
```

Below are the 2 lines which work which use ' (single quotes)

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( _x( 'username', 'example username' ), ENT_QUOTES ); ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( _x( 'password', 'example password' ), ENT_QUOTES ); ?>" autocomplete="off" />
```

Below are the 2 lines which **DO NOT** work which use " (double quotes)

```
<td><input name="dbname" id="dbname" type="text" aria-describedby="dbname-desc" size="25" value="wordpress"<?php echo $autofocus; ?>/></td>
<td><input name="prefix" id="prefix" type="text" aria-describedby="prefix-desc" value="wp_" size="25" /></td>
```

When replacing words with double quotes around them, it does not do it **"wordpress"** and **"wp_"**.

I tried the following:

```
sed -i -e "s/( '"wordpress"'/( '$varname'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
sed -i -e "s/( "'"wordpress"'"/( '$varname'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
sed -i -e "s/( '""wordpress""'/( '$varname'/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: What is it supposed to replace on those lines? There's no `( )` around `"wordpress"`

Comment: If I am correct, wordpress would be replace with $varname which the database name in this case.

Comment: But you're looking for `( "wordpress`, not just `"wordpress`

Comment: I should ONLY be looking for "wordpress". Then is should be? ```sed -i -e "s/ 'wordpress'/``` ?

Comment: Then why do you have `(` before it? And why do all your attempts have single quotes in the pattern, when you want to look for double quotes?

Comment: `sed -i 's/"wordpress"/"'"$varname"'"/g' filename` should work for lines containing `value="wordpress"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to define a variable that contains a double quote, then you can use that inside the string.

```
q='"'
sed -i -e "s/${q}wordpress${q}/${q}$varname${q}/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
```

Or you can escape the double quotes:

```
q='"'
sed -i -e "s/\"wordpress\"/\"$varname\"/g" "/var/www/$domainname/html/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
```

Either way, you shouldn't have any single quotes in the regexp.